# Не получается перебрать массив в Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Пытаюсь перебрать массив, результат должен быть таким(в столбик):

```
24 
45 
98 
34 
22 
55
```

Вот мой код, не пойму почему не работает, выдает ошибку в строке for, не пойму что тут не так.
Насколько я понимаю интерпретатору что то не нравиться.

```
#!/bin/bash

mass=(24 45 98 34 22 55)

for((i=0;i<${mass[@]};i++)); do

echo "$i"

done
```

Вот сама ошибка:

```
Error(s), warning(s):

392036285/source.sh: line 4: ((: 0 < 24 45 98 34 22 55: syntax error in expression (error token is "45 98 34 22 55")
```

Подскажите в чем дело?

P.S. Также хочу сложить сначала первую половину цифр, а потом вторую и сравнить их.

Answer (score 3):

Для получения длины массива перед его именем надо добавить `#`

```
for((i=0;i<${#mass[@]};i++)); do
```

Кроме того, вместо `echo "$i"` надо выводить соотв. элемент массива: `echo "${mass[i]}"`

Однако еще проще будет использовать `for ... in`

```
#!/bin/bash

mass=(24 45 98 34 22 55)

for i in ${mass[@]}
do
    echo "${i}"
done
```

Comment: если Вас не затруднит могли бы вы объяснить когда нужно применять(использовать) for i in ..... , а когда for((i=0;i<10;i++))  ????

Comment: Ну когда надо просто получить каждый элемент из массива, то тогда `for ... in`, а если нужны именно индексы, то `for((i=0;i<10;i++))`

Comment: Если нужны только индексы, то `seq ${#mass[@]}`

Comment: @DiD seq лучше не использовать, так как обычно это внешняя утилита.

Comment: @user7860670, если использует `echo`, то может использовать и `seq`. Как правило, они входят в пакет `coreutils`

Comment: @DiD `echo` - это встроенная директива

Comment: Кстати, говоря о высоком, лучше использовать в скриптах интерпретатор `/bin/sh` чем `/bin/bash`. Автор вопроса на своём опыте пока не сталкивался с проблемами, а они обязательно появляются, когда скрипт используется не только на компьютере, где непосредственно его написали.

Comment: @DiD sh не должен использовать для интерпретации bash скрипта

Comment: @user7860670 я имел в виду что `bash` больше создавался для ручного ввода, а `sh` для скриптов. В `bash` синтаксис меняется на каждой версии, а в `sh` остается как был 28 лет назад.

Comment: Очень заинтересовало насчет bash и sh. Если можно более подробнее разъясните

Answer (score 0):

Еще перебрать массив можно таким способом:

```
mass=(24 45 98 34 22 55)

xargs -n1 echo <<<${mass[*]}
```

`xargs` очень интересная команда, она преобразует текст из входящего потока в параметры для запуска команд и программ. Очень мощный инструмент. `xargs` в одну строчку организует очередь выполнения большого количества однотипных задач в заданное количество процессов(потоков). Подробно по команде `man xargs`.

Индексы можно вывести так:

```
seq ${#mass[@]}
```

Команда `seq` работает как счётчик, содержит от одного до трех параметров:

```
seq считать_от считать_до шаг_счета
seq считать_от считать_до
seq считать_до
```

Можно другой подход:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<<${mass[@]}
```

`tr` заменяет символы одни на другие

Если `mass` был бы строкой, то можно было бы сделать так:

```
mass="24 45 98 34 22 55"
echo -e ${mass// /\\n}
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось перебрать с помощью этого кода:

```
#!/bin/bash

mass=(24 45 98 34 22 55)

for i in ${mass[@]}
do
    echo "${i}"
done
```